# Custom package import issue

Tags: python, python-import

I have a project with the following file structure:

```
main.py
my_pkg:
    __init__.py
    utility.py
    a.py
```

`a.py` looks like:

```
import utility
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
```

when I run `a.py`, it runs smoothly.

`main.py` looks like:

```
from my_pkg import a
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
```

when I run `main.py`, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utility'
```

not sure how to resolve it...

Comment: show how you are importing

Comment: In init did you write something like from .utility import * ?

Comment: nope. the init file is empty.